# Xcode says No code signing identities found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

In Xcode, when I try to Build an existing app, I get an error:
"Code Sign Error: No codesigning identities found:..."

In the app's Build Settings, I have selected the Provisioning Profile for the app, but in Code Signing Identity the only thing I can get is "iPhone Developer". When I click on that, the popup also tells me "No Identities from Profile "..."".

So apparently there's something wrong with the Provisioning Profile or identity.

When I edit the Provisioning Profile, I am only given three options, all of them are identities with the same name and various dates. I chose the one with the latest expiration date.

I tried deleting the Profile and certificate from my library and Keychain, then downloaded them and double-clicked on the files to reinstall them. No change.

I do see that Keychain Access is not showing the triangle next to my certificate, but I'm not being offered a private key at any point.

In Developer Member Center, in iOS Certificates (Production), I did try clicking on the + icon to create a new certificate, but the option to create an App Store certificate is greyed out. I can't tell if the existing certificates are for the App Store... clicking on them only gives me the option to Revoke or Download.

Apparently I somehow need to get a private key, but I'm not seeing a way to retrieve nor create one. The Member Center is not telling me if I've encountered a three-certificate limit or something, nor whether revoking something will interfere with what is in the App Store... not that a revocation seems needed, as I'm trying to add and not interfere with other developers.

UPDATE: I couldn't find a valid identity for the Provisioning Profile, so I created a new Production Certificate (iOS Distribution), then chose that in the Provisioning Profile. Downloaded both and added them to the machine. Restarted Xcode. Now that identity is visible, and the build passes Verification.

But iTunes rejects it with a list of a bunch of possible reasons. One solution, "Clean All" seems to not be in Xcode (only a "Clean" option), so I don't know how much to trust in the message.

"Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target."

Yes, I'm certain that everything is right... I was certain each of the dozens of times that I submitted the app.

Comment: Open the profiles with `more`, `less` or even `vim` on the Terminal and look for the signing identity in the profile (if the Terminal complains about it being a binary file, type y to open it anyway). Then open the keychain and search for the same signing identity. Check the Id. This should lead you to the underlying problem.

Comment: I'm not finding an identity -- but then, Xcode is telling me "No codesigning identities", so maybe there isn't one defined, although I think that I'm seeing one in the Member Center Provisioning Profile and Certificate pop-opens.

Comment: In the mobile provisioning file look for the value for the key `TeamIdentifier`. Then open the keychain an search in the info (cmd+i) of the certificates if you can find this team identifier.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this question is in regards to an iOS project, but I had a similar problem with my Mac app. Even though I had selected "Don't Code Sign", Xcode was still complaining about a missing identity.

I solved it by manually editing the file `<Project>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and deleting all lines defining `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` or `CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS`.

This might get you back to coding, but obviously won't be a final solution if you intend to submit to the App Store.